# How can I check Windows version and conditional-compile a section of code based on this version using Cabal?

Tags: windows, haskell, build, cabal, c-preprocessor

Given the following piece of code

```
(@<) :: Port -> IO Socket
(@<) p = do -- listen
#if !defined(IPV4ONLY)
  s <- socket AF_INET6 Stream 0 =>> opt
  setSocketOption s IPv6Only  0 // try_
  bindSocket      s $ SockAddrInet6 p 0 iN6ADDR_ANY 0
#else
  s <- socket AF_INET  Stream 0 =>> opt              -- Windows XP does not have
  setSocketOption s $ SockAddrInet  p   iNADDR_ANY   -- a dual-stack sockets API
#endif
  listen          s maxListenQueue
  print $ Service Listen p
  return s
    where opt s = mapM_ (\o -> setSocketOption s o 1) [ ReuseAddr, KeepAlive ]
```

what is the cleanest / shortest way at configuration (cabal config) time to:

1. check Windows version
2. define `IPV4ONLY` if compiling on Windows XP (or earlier?)

A Cabal-only way to do this is preferred. As I believe the check is too tiny to create full-fledged configure scripts

Comment: Not writing this as a complete answer, because there's still a lot of things left out, but you can use `System.Info.os` in `Setup.hs` to detect the operating system and the [`Cabal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal) API to modify how your project is built.

Comment: Wow never ever heard of a Cabal API. `System.Info` in general and `System.Info.os` in particular (which reads `mingw32` on all Windows versions / editions) are completely useless in many cases. I hope there has long been something like `uname` on Windows which might keep changes to Setup.hs trivial :)

Comment: @Cetin Sert - `mingw32` is a fair description for Windows as GHC ships with various build tools from the mingw project (even g++ if I remember correctly). As for establishing Windows version that's a bit trickier...

Comment: A poor mans solution would be to use a cabal flag which users with XP or earlier must manually set, this flag would set the relevant `cpp-options` in the cabal file. Similar example here: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2010-February/013026.html

Comment: how do i tell cabal which flags to use at the command line?